# Windows Phone 7 - CSS input styling

Tags: css, windows-phone-7, border

I'm working on a website that needs to cater for a range of mobile devices.
Personally I own a HTC Trophy with Windows Phone 7.5.

I am seeing a strange and annoying styling issue
where form inputs (text boxes, select, text areas etc) are being outlined strongly in black.

This isn't in my stylesheet!

Google searches have shown nothing up (I guess no one is caring about poor winp7)

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you include what CSS you do have? And a screenshot if possible? Do you see the black outline when you strip the CSS altogether?